# Is there a term for methods or functions that answer an inquiry

Tags: computer-science, terminology

Is there a computer science term for methods that answer a question (i.e. `is_kind_of`, `not_nil?`, `isEmpty`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that returns only a true-or-false result is called a "predicate method".

Answer (score 0):

Most methods named like these presented by you return `boolean` value (value returned by these methods is logical `true` or `false`), so sometimes these methods are called *boolean methods*, but I don't think it can be called as scientific name for this type of method.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a query. There answer is the response.